# Circular Referencing ...Just to show Forms of Different Projects

Tags: c#

I am a newbie to C# and i have some difficulty in integrating two different projects. 
The scenario is:

Project A and Project B are Working on a Same Project. Project A has many Forms. I have added Project B as a reference for Project A to show a Form in Project B by instantiating the Form. Now , once the Instantiated  Form shows up and the user clicks on a button...I want to show up a Form which is in Project A. But, due to Circular Referencing...i am not able to achieve it.

I read about using interfaces in these kind of cases. But, i am not sure how to use an interface for passing Form as an object.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the forms 1 (project A), 2 (project B) and 3 (also project A).

When you open Form2 from Form1, pass an anonymous method/lambda that enables Form2 to open Form3.

In Form2:

```
public Action OpenForm3 { get; set; }
```

In Form1, after instantiating but before showing Form2:

```
myForm2.OpenForm3 = () => { var myForm3 = new Form3(); myForm3.ShowDialog(); };
```

In Form3:

```
this.OpenForm3.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about a state manager object to your project. The problem is that the view from project B(Form B) directly direct the user to a view from project A (Form A) and vice versa so each project depends on the other project. 
You can create an infrastructure project
which handles states so for each state of the client you show a particular view by defining rules (by xml or something like that).
So, when the user click on the button you tell the state manager object that the user clicked a button from form B,the state manager see in its rules that from its current state and the current action it should go to another state,and the view of the other state is Form A.