# C# Forms Inactive / Threading Processes

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two projects (Project A & Project B) with multiple WinForms in each of them . Forms are instantiated by each other in one or the other events as described in my earlier question ([Circular Referencing ...Just to show Forms of Different Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854883/circular-referencing-just-to-show-forms-of-different-projects)).

Upon instantiation of a Form and making it visible, the Parent Forms gets inactive. I want the Forms which are visible to be active and working anytime i need . I believe its  a threading problem. But i don't know much about to help myself.

Please help...

Comment: You're probably using `Form.ShowDialog()` instead of `Form.Show()`

Comment: Please put this as an Answer. That Worked. I'll tick that as an Answer. BTW, what's the difference between ShowDialog() and Show Method() @GrawCube .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using [`Form.ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`Form.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Form.ShowDialog shows the form as a modal dialog box, meaning that it must be closed before any code execution in the method that called ShowDialog can continue.